# Android Pass data from EditText to notification to dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-alertdialog

I have an activity that has an EditText. After a user enters their text, the app may use that text later to make a notification. I can set the notification text just fine, but when the user clicks on the notification, it launches a dialog box that should have the same text. I have tried putExtra with the PendingIntent but that only displays the latest text in the dialog no matter which notification was selected. Is there a way to assign each string from the EditText  a number and have the dialog load the text from what number it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following logic,

make one static string variable,

```
private static strEditText = null;
```

at the time of EditText input, just store its value ion to strEditText variable like below,

```
strEditText = EditText.getText().toString().trim();
```

Now make one public static method, like below,

```
public static String EditTextValue()
{
      return strEditText;
}
```

Now you can have this variable's value throughout whole project.

You can also try another method in android,

pass your arguments in `Bundle`

Comment: It sounds like this would make one string for all the dialogs. This is exactly what I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The PendingIntents are pooled/cached and the extra's don't make them different entries, so if you have a bunch of notifications with pendingIntents and the only difference between the intents are extras, then you'll end up with the notifications all using the one of the pendingIntents. [This sounds like what you're seeing, I remember this driving me nuts for a while]. You need to make your pending intents differ in something that the pool/cache cares about, like the data URI or action.

Comment: I have a notification ID int that is used to determine which notification is pressed. I'll see if I can work that into the extras somehow.